# How to solve keyboard problems in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, keyboard

The problem is that when I try to write in the text fields the keyboard cover them up. How can I scroll the text field up to see what am I writing. I have below lines of code to enable the return key and to hide the keyboard when you touch in a different place:

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
  super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I scroll the text field up to see what am I writing

This can be achieved in two ways:

1. You can manage your frame programmatically on keyboard hide and show like @Taichi Kato
2. You can integrate libraries which serves the same purpose. One such library is **`IQKeyBoardManager`** with its Swift variant as **`IQKeyboardManagerSwift`** You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) and [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/IQKeyboardManagerSwift)

To achieve follow the below steps :

**SWIFT 3**

1. Just install `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` from Github or cocoapods
2. Import `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` in `Appdelegate`
3. Add the below lines of code in `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

   ```
   IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true;
   ```

**Objective-C**

1. Install `IQKeyBoardManager` via any medium
2. Import `#import "IQKeyboardManager.h"` in `Appdelegate`
3. Add the below lines of code in `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

   ```
   IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true;
   ```

And this is **Done**. This is the only code which you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this problem is to put all the elements into one scrollview and then add the keyboard height to the constant of the bottom of the view to superview.

When the keyboard is shown or hidden, iOS sends out the following notifications to any registered observers:

UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
UIKeyboardDidHideNotification

So here is what you can do:

1. Get the size of the keyboard.
2. Adjust the bottom content inset of
   your scroll view by the keyboard height.
3. Scroll the target text
   field into view.

Something like this:

```
 func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("KEYBOARD WILL SHOW")
        let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight + 8
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded() ?? ()
        })

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
        bottomConstraint.constant = 8
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded() ?? ()
        })
    }
```

Comment: where is `bottomConstraint` coming from? I'm getting an `unresolved identifier` error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this two `framework` for `keyboard` problem solved:

- IQKeyboardManager : [Link](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)
- iOSUtilitiesSource: [Link](https://github.com/hasnine/iOSUtilitiesSource)