# How to Move TextField when Keyboard appear in Tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uiscrollview, uitextfield

When I used **UITableViewCell** and inside **UITableViewCell** used **UITextField**, so how to move **UITextField** when Keyboard comes up?

Comment: you can use IQkeyboardManger for this.

Comment: when you click on the textField it automatically appear above the keyboard because you have taken textfield inside the cell and tableView is subclass of UIScrollView.

Comment: @Jaydip You can try this https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839366/how-to-solve-keyboard-problems-in-swift-3/42361236#42361236